# NLTK stemmer returns a list of NoneTypes

Tags: python, arrays, nlp, nltk

I am preprocessing text data,(twitter data to be exact), but whenever I apply the NLTK stemmer I get a list of NoneTypes. I can't figure out why this happens and I have no idea how to solve it.

This is how my text data looks through processing:

**Before processing:**

```
In [10]:
undefined



import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import glob
import os
import nltk
dir = "C:\Users\Anonymous\Desktop\KAGA FOLDER\Hashtags"
train = np.array(pd.read_csv(os.path.join(dir,"train.csv")))[:,1]
def clean_the_text(data):
    alist = []
    data = nltk.word_tokenize(data)
    for j in data:
        alist.append(j.rstrip('\n'))
    alist = " ".join(alist)
    return alist

def stemmer(data):
    stemmer = nltk.stem.PorterStemmer()
    new_list = []
    new_list = [new_list.append(stemmer.stem(word)) for word in data]
    return new_list
def loop_data(data):
    for i in range(len(data)):
        data[i] = clean_the_text(data[i])
    return data
train


Out[10]:
array(['Jazz for a Rainy Afternoon:  {link}',
       'RT: @mention: I love rainy days.',
       'Good Morning Chicago! Time to kick the Windy City in the nuts and head back West!',
       ...,
       'OMG #WeatherForecast for tomm 80 degrees & Sunny &lt;=== #NeedThat #Philly #iMustSeeItToBelieveIt yo',
       "@mention Oh no! We had cold weather early in the week, but now it's getting warmer! Hoping the rain holds out to Saturday!",
       'North Cascades Hwy to reopen Wed.: quite late after a long, deep winter. Only had to clear snow 75 ft deep {link}'], dtype=object)
```

**After tokenizing and cleaning text:**

```
train = loop_data(train)

In [12]:
undefined



train
Out[12]:
array(['Jazz for a Rainy Afternoon : { link }',
       'RT : @ mention : I love rainy days .',
       'Good Morning Chicago ! Time to kick the Windy City in the nuts and head back West !',
       ...,
       'OMG # WeatherForecast for tomm 80 degrees & Sunny & lt ; === # NeedThat # Philly # iMustSeeItToBelieveIt yo',
       "@ mention Oh no ! We had cold weather early in the week , but now it 's getting warmer ! Hoping the rain holds out to Saturday !",
       'North Cascades Hwy to reopen Wed. : quite late after a long , deep winter. Only had to clear snow 75 ft deep { link }'], dtype=object)
```

**And finally after stemming:**

```
In [13]:
undefined



train = stemmer(train)
train
Out[13]:
[None,
 None,
 None,
 None,
 None,
 None,
 None,
 None,
 None,
 None,
 None,
 None,
 None,
 None,
 None,
 None,
 None,
 None,
 None,
 None,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here: `new_list = [new_list.append(stemmer.stem(word)) for word in data]`. It should be

```
new_list = [stemmer.stem(word) for word in data]
# or 
# new_data = map(stemmer.stem, data) # returns a map object
```

`new_list` is being append len(data) times then it is being set to a new list from the list comprehension statement containing len(data) results of `new_list.append` which is None.

Comment: Thank you very much. that was indeed the problem.